# Properties of 3D waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I have a few questions about 3D waves:

1. Are all 3D waves types of electromagnetic radiation?
2. Are all 2D waves mechanical?

Comment: 1) No.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @jinawee how would you give a definition of a 3dimensional wave then? What sets them apart from 2 and 1D waves?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to define a wave, but sound waves are clearly three dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple definition of a wave is as follows,

> a wave is a disturbance that travels through a medium

A three-dimensional wave satisfies the partial differential equation,
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2}=\alpha\nabla^2f\tag{1}
$$
where $f$ is some function that could be EM or mechanical in origin and $\alpha$ some constant that helps out with dimensions. Sound propagation, waves on a surface, and electromagnetic radiation are examples of solutions to this equation.

In the case of 2D, Equation (1) becomes
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2}=\alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)f\tag{2}$$
so any function $f$ that satisfies this could be called a 2D wave; it need not be mechanical only.